# count changes based on timestamp

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
timestamp   ip        score
1432632348  1.2.3.4   9
1432632434  5.6.7.8   8
1432632447  1.2.3.4   9
1432632456  1.2.3.4   8
1432632460  5.6.7.8   8
1432632464  1.2.3.4   9
```

The timestamps are consecutive, but don't have any frequency. I want to count, per IP, the number of times the score changed. so in the example the result would be:

```
ip      count
1.2.3.4 3
5.6.7.8 1
```

How can I do that? (note: count distinct does not work: 1.2.3.4 changed 3 times but had 2 distinct scores)

Comment: which dbms are you using

Comment: you could do self join `on a.ip = b.ip and a.score <> b.score`

Comment: Add some more 1.2.3.4 rows, alternating score 8 and 9!

Comment: Depending on the table size, I would consider droping the table to a csv, sort them and then use awk to count the changes

Comment: I still can not understand why it changed 3 times? It was 9 then it became 9... is this change?

Comment: Elaborate on where there is change and where is not. It is not clear. What is timestamp and when does it come in play?

Comment: (a) The count for what you have described for 1.2.3.4 is 2, not 3. (b) `DISTINCT` and changes are two different things.

Comment: The op doesn't even bother about eleborating on his question. Why the question is upvoted at all?

Comment: @IttayD . . . The question is unclear.  The text says "score changes", yet the sample data suggests that the logic is just one less than the number of appearances.

Comment: a) The timestamps given are increasing, not consecutive. (b) please review the answers, comment, ask question vote up, choose, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ip,
       sum(case when score <> (select t2.score from table t2
                               where t2.timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from table
                                                     where ip = t2.ip
                                                       and timestamp < t1.timestamp)
                                 and t1.ip = t2.ip) then 1 else 0 end)
from table t1
group by ip
```

Comment: Plus 1 for solution in one query. It has a really bad performance though.

Comment: In Sql Server throws exception:
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: Ha ha, it may be slow, but I don't know dbms, or amount of data, or index/keys.

Comment: @4thfloorstudios.  Performance of subqueries and derived tables are just fine in commercial SQL platforms.  The freeware is a different story

Comment: PerformanceDBA: Yep, problem won't be the subqueries but the GROUP BY, jarlh: That's true! Assumed SQL based DB :)

Answer (score 1):

Although this requirement is not common, it is not rare either.  Basically, you need to determine when there is a change in the data column.

The data is Relational, therefore the solution is Relation.  No Cursors or CTEs or `ROW_NUMBER()s` or temp tables or `GROUP BYs` or scripts or triggers are required.  `DISTINCT` will not work.  The solution is straight-forward.  But you have to keep your Relational hat on.

```
    SELECT  COUNT( timestamp )
        FROM (

        SELECT  timestamp,
                ip,
                score,
                [score_next] = (
            SELECT  TOP 1
                    score               -- NULL if not exists
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE ip        = MT.ip
                AND   timestamp > MT.timestamp
                )

            FROM MyTable MT

            ) AS X

        WHERE score      != score_next  -- exclude unchanging rows
        AND   score_next != NULL
```

I note that for the data you have given, the output should be:

```
    ip      count
    1.2.3.4     2
    5.6.7.8     0
```

- if you have been counted the last score per ip, which hasn't changed yet, then your figures will by "out-by-1".  To obtain your counts, delete that last line of code.
- if you have been counting an stated `0` as a starting value, add `1` to the `COUNT().`

If you interested in more discussion of the not-uncommon problem, I have given a full treatment in [**this Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30460263/484814).

Answer (score -2):

```
select ip ,
       count(distinct score) 
 from YourTable 
 group by ip
```

[image]